# Strange characters when printing a list

Tags: python, list, special-characters

I got an exercise that i need to print the highest value at a given letter that represent a column.

The code works, but the printing of the list has some characthers that i dont know how to get rid of:

['ï»¿A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

As you can see there are some characthers before the letter A.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

Book = open("Book1.csv","r")

MaxValue = 0
LettLocation = 0

print('Enter column letter:')
FindChar = input()

import csv
with open("Book1.csv", newline='') as f:
  Reader = csv.reader(f)
  FirstRow = next(Reader)
  print(FirstRow)
  for Incre in range(len(FirstRow)):
    if FirstRow[Incre] == FindChar:
        LettLocation = Incre
        break
    
  for row in Reader:
    FirstValue = int(row[LettLocation])
    if MaxValue < FirstValue:
        MaxValue = FirstValue

print("At column", FindChar, "The highest value is:", MaxValue)
```

Comment: your CSV file begins with a BOM character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are byte order marks (BOM) from your file being read in.
Specify an encoding first, in your parameters, like so: `encoding='utf-8-sig'`